# How to provide x-axis and y-axis values in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, 3d, charts, webgl

am trying to use WebGL to plot a 3D surface. My problem is that it is not letting me provide the x and the y values. It plots the z axis values against the values of x ranging from 0 to n and the values of y ranging from 0 to m (all integral values).

How can I make a surface where I can also provide the x and the y values for the 3D surface construction. Also if its not possible to do it in WebGL then what solution can I use?

PS Also, WebGL tooltip function doesnt function. any comments on that?

Comment: It sounds like you are using a library which uses WebGL, not WebGL itself — WebGL does not have “plots”, “surfaces”, or “tooltips”. If you specify what that library is (particularly in the title and tags of your question) then you will be more likely to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are saying that you can't specify the scale of x and y relative to the plotted (z) value?

What you need is to apply a non-uniform scale to the entire surface (the modelview matrix), so that the X and Y axes are stretched into the shape you want. Are you using three.js or a similar library, or... ? The answer will define the specific commands you should use.

As an example, let's say that you have a 100x50 plot, with the spacing forced by the library to 1.0 between x and y. Instead, you want the size to be 300x200 in x and y. You would scale the matrix by (3,4,1).

If you want to change the displayed range of your Z data, I would suggest adjusting its zero point (i.e., translating it up or down to be centered) and then scaling appropriately as-needed.